# Network send problem

Tags: c++, qt4

I try to send data over the network, but the server I've programmed doesen't get the data.
This code worked befor:

```
void MainWindow::send()
{
 QByteArray qbarr;
 QDataStream qdstrm(&qbarr, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
 int iCount = qlist->count();
 QProgressDialog qprogrsdSend(QString("Sending..."), QString("Cancel"), 0, iCount, this);

 qdstrm.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_6);

 qprogrsdSend.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);

 for(int i = 0; i < iCount; i++)
 {
  if(qprogrsdSend.wasCanceled())
   break;

  qdstrm << (quint16)0;
  qdstrm << (*qlist)[i].data();
  qdstrm.device()->seek(0);
  qdstrm << (quint16)(qbarr.size() - sizeof(quint16));

  qprogrsdSend.setValue(i);

  qtcpsoClient->write(qbarr);
  qtcpsoClient->flush();
  qtcpsoClient->waitForBytesWritten();

  qbarr.clear();
 }

 qlblStatus2->setText("File is send.");
}
```

But it Takes to many time to send each elemt from qlist. Now I tried to modify the methode, so that first all elements from qlist has been saved in qbarr. And than I send the File. This is the code that doesnt work:

```
void MainWindow::send()
{
 QByteArray qbarr;
 QDataStream qdstrm(&qbarr, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
 int iCount = qlist->count();
 QProgressDialog qprogrsdSend(QString("Sending..."), QString("Cancel"), 0, iCount, this);

 qdstrm.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_6);

 qprogrsdSend.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);

 qdstrm << (quint16)0;

 for(int i = 0; i < iCount; i++)
 {
  if(qprogrsdSend.wasCanceled())
   break;

  qdstrm << (*qlist)[i].data();

  qprogrsdSend.setValue(i);
 }

 qdstrm.device()->seek(0);
 qdstrm << (quint16)(qbarr.size() - sizeof(quint16));

 qtcpsoClient->write(qbarr);
 qtcpsoClient->flush();
 qtcpsoClient->waitForBytesWritten();

 qbarr.clear();

 qlblStatus2->setText("File is send.");
}
```

And here is the methode I use to read the data:

```
void QServerThread::onReadyRead(void)
{
 if(read == false)
 {
  read = true;
  emit reading(true);
 }

 while(!qtcpsoClient->atEnd())
 {
  QDataStream qdstrmIn(qtcpsoClient);
  QDataStream qdstrmOut(qfile);
  QByteArray qbarrData;
  quint16 qui16BlockSize = 0;
  int iVersion = qdstrmIn.version();

  qdstrmIn.setVersion(iVersion);
  qdstrmOut.setVersion(iVersion);

  if(qtcpsoClient->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16))
   break;

  qdstrmIn >> qui16BlockSize;

  if(qtcpsoClient->bytesAvailable() < qui16BlockSize)
   break;

  qdstrmIn >> qbarrData;

  qdstrmOut << qbarrData.data();

  qfile->flush();
 }

 read = false;
 emit reading(false);
}
```

I hope somebody can help me.
Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't the problem be in your server? I suppose you connect your onReadyRead to readyRead singal of the socket. That signal is emitted once per a chunk of data received. So if you send all your data at once, it is possible the signal gets emitted only once. I suppose `qtcpsoClient` is the socket. Now, I can see this happening:

You ask `bytesAvailable() < somesize` before that much data arrived yet. In that case you read a size, but break out right after that and on next read you already lost your size information and read garbage.

This might not be a problem before as you send multiple short messages, and every message managed to fully arrive before you asked for the data size. The bug was still there though.

On a sidenote. In your original client code - why did you `flush()` and `waitForBytesWritten()` after every `write`? This may be the reason why it was so slow.

[edit: corrected based on Sergey Tachenov's comment]

Comment: The "never return" part is not exactly true. onReadyRead() will get called again, only this time instead of the next block size it will read some arbitrary data. The behavior is undefined then. Otherwise, the answer is correct.

Comment: @Sergey oh, so `readyRead` is emitted every time the value returned by `bytesAvailable()` changes? I suppose I always anticipated the worst case scenario, so I never noticed this behaviour.

Comment: More precisely, readyRead() is emited once and only once when some data arrives in the input buffer, with the exception that it is never emitted recursively. This is actually useful as you don't have to read anything into a temporary buffer if there's not enough data yet. That is, assuming that you know how much exactly is enough.

Comment: The two bytesAvailable()-requests I've taken from the Fortune Client example of the Qt Documentation. But I've already deletet that part. The flush() and waitForBytesWritten() is only for the for-loop because the write()-methode sends only wenn my send()-methode ends.

Comment: @Paul so .. is it working now? The use of `bytesAvailable()` in [Fortune Client](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/network-blockingfortuneclient.html) example is correct, because if you notice in case there are not enough bytes available, they wait in a loop for more, instead of breaking away.